# Need solution to schedule Spark jobs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark.
In our project,

1. we have converted seven PLSql scripts into Scala-Spark.
2. The existing PLSql scripts are scheduled as jobs on Talend. Each
   script is a scheduled on a separate job and these seven jobs run on a sequence as only after the first job completes successfully, the second job starts and same continues until the last job(seventh).

My team is exploring the possibilities to schedule the Scala-Spark programs as jobs in other ways. One of the suggestion was to convert/write the same job that is running on Talend into Scala. I have no idea if it is possible. 
So, Could anyone let me know whether it is possible to do the same on Scala.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your spark job in Talend using tSystem or tSSH component. and get the response code (exit code) from the mentioned component. If the exit code=0 (Success) then you can submit next spark job. We did the same in our project.

Comment: Okay. I narrowed it to Talend now. Another thing is that the existing Talend job has some intermediate GP functions like Timestamp conversion, table column initialization, etc. Is it good to convert them into Spark and schedule all of them on Talend or leave those Intermediate GP functions as they are ? All the metadata of the PLSql scripts is present on Hive too. So I need some advice on this.